# WebStorm "cannot find declaration to go to" for ID in HTML

Tags: html, css, editor, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

In JetBrains WebStorm 2023.2.2, navigating to style declarations for classes works well with `Ctrl`-click, however for `id`s it does not work.

Example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <title>Title</title>
   <style>
      #i1 {color: red}
      .c1 {font-size: 15px}
   </style>
</head>

<body>
<p id="i1" class="c1">test</p>
</body>
</html>
```

When I `Ctrl`-click the `c1` in the HTML, it navigates to the `.c1` in the CSS, but when I `Ctrl`-click `i1` it says "Cannot find declaration to go to":

[image]

The same for an external style sheet.

Also, when the cursor is placed at the `c1` in the HTML, the `c1` in the CSS is highlighted, but when the cursor is placed in the `i1` of the HTML, `i1` in the CSS is not highlighted.

*Do others experience the same or may this be a problem with my WebStorm or project configuration?*

Comment: Hmm.. PhpStorm 2023.1.4 (yeah, still have not found a moment to upgrade from the previous version). Tried your code in my test project, plain HTML file and it works just fine: clicking on `i1` in `<p id="i1" class="c1">test</p>` line jumps to `#i1` CSS declaration just fine.

Comment: What I may suggest: 1) Try this in a brand new project. 2) What kind of file is that? Just plain HTML or some template lang/processor gets involved? 3) If you have any custom/3rd party plugins (not bundled by default) installed -- disabled then, restart the IDE and try again -- any difference?

Comment: @LazyOne thanks for your help. Tried brand new project already, plain HTML. Will investigate further now.

Comment: Have now restored default settings (from `File`> `Manage IDE Settings`), created new `Empty Project`, created HTML file, pasted above code, still the same (not working for `i1`)

Comment: Just to double check: any custom plugins? It works here (as fas as I understand your issue and the code): https://i.imgur.com/NZiN808.gif But who knows, maybe in WebStorm 2023.2 it is actually broken.... P.S. Just wondering, will it find it if you invoke Search Everywhere (`Shift` + `Shift`), switch to Symbols tab and search for `i1` there? If yes -- what results it will show (what lines etc). Show a screenshot.

Comment: ALSO: please post a screenshot of how this file looks in the actual IDE. 1) I want to see the editor tab/file icon as well. So better make a full size screenshot. 2) Please use standard bundled color scheme. Ideally light one (or Darcula). Colors may matter. I'm just checking one theory. I think it will not be the case, especially since you have used "restore default settings" already...

Comment: https://ibb.co/54S9xzx, https://ibb.co/NYNhdNS, https://ibb.co/xYHX5Gr. In the first screenshot you see that `c1` is highlighting, in the 2nd you see that `i1` is not, in the 3rd that Search Everywhere works correctly for `i1`. Default light color theme. I checked that all custom plugins were uninstalled after restoring default settings.

Comment: Looks OK to me. In such a case: either wait a bit for JetBrains support to comment here (they check daily, at least during week days) or report it to WebStorm Support (`Help | Contact Support...` from the WebStorm menu -- it will take you to their website to make a [private Support ticket](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/requests/new?ticket_form_id=66731). If it's an issue that needs fixing you or them can then make a ticket on [WebStorm Issue Tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WEB))